# Stacked Bar Chart for Gene Expression in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am new to data visualization. I am trying to use R to visualize `DEseq2` data from `galaxy` to show the range of expression of genes on different chromosomes between males and female of a beetle species. I need the `X` to be chromosome and the `Y` to be expression level (`log2FC`).

I am trying to have this produce a color gradient going from male to female, like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX1BT.png).

I have tried to do this using a standard barchart, creating a joined group for `gender-log2fc`:

```
sexlinked=read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)
df <- sexlinked
df$group <- paste0(df$sex, "-", df$log2fc, sep="")
ggplot(df, aes(chromosomes)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = group), colour = "grey")
```

Here is an image of my [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYsMG.jpg) (screencap of spreadsheet), in case it helps you to assist me.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! I have updated my question. Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`.